# access to value of array php

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

Array code:

```
        $membership = wc_memberships_get_user_active_memberships(get_current_user_id());
        $membership = $membership[0];
        print("<pre>".print_r($membership,true)."</pre>");
```

Small part of output:

```
WC_Memberships_User_Membership Object
(
    [id] => 784
    [plan_id] => 446
    [plan] => WC_Memberships_Membership_Plan Object
        (
            [id] => 446
            [name] => Test
            [slug] => membership
            [post] => WP_Post Object
```

I want to get [plan_id]. I tried

```
$membership = get_object_vars($obj);
echo $obj->plan_id;
```

and

```
echo $membership[plan_id]
```

But it makes critical php error. What I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I got this:

```
foreach ($memberships as $membership => $val) {
    echo $val->plan->id . '<br>';
};
```

Hope it will be helpful for someone